# Использование std::thread и std::mutex. Поделитесь опытом

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11

Решил разобраться в вопросе *"Как писать эффективные многопоточные приложения/алгоритмы?"*

Для эксперимента решено написать программу, которая генерирует последовательность байт заданного размера.
Написаны функции:

1. `void GenSeqByte(std::ofstream &stream, size_t byte)`, которая разбивает задание на потоки (тело функции ниже);
2. `void GenAndWriteSeq(std::ofstream &stream, size_t &bytes, std::mutex &m)`, непосредственно генерирует последовательность.

---

Тут все понятно.

```
void GenSeqByte(std::ofstream &stream, size_t byte)
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(GenAndWriteSeq, std::ref(stream), std::ref(byte), std::ref(mtx)));
    }

    for (auto &t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Функция `GenAndWriteSeq(...)` генерирует последовательность `bufSize * sizeof(int)` байт и записывает ее в выходной файл (предполагается, что это повысит эффективность, вместо постоянного вызова `write()`). Запись продолжается, пока мы не запишем нужное количество байт.

```
void GenAndWriteSeq(std::ofstream &stream, size_t &bytes, std::mutex &m)
{
    std::random_device seed;
    std::mt19937 gen(seed());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
    // 1 KByte buffer.
    constexpr size_t bufSize = 1024 / sizeof(int);
    int buf[bufSize];

    while (true)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) {
            buf[i] = dist(gen);
        }

        if (bytes > 0) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m);

            if (bytes > 0) {
                stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buf), bytes > bufSize ? bufSize : bytes);
                if (bytes > bufSize) {
                    bytes -= bufSize;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } 
        return;
    }
}
```

Прошу поделиться опытом и подсказать, как можно улучшить данный фрагмент кода. Лучшим вариантом будет подсказать, привести пример, и сослаться на какой нибудь источник (например, профессиональная литература).

---

Так же есть прямой вопрос.
У нас имеется разделяемая между потоками память. Мы делим ее на непересекающиеся области и передаем разным потокам.

```
void foo(double *a, int b) { for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i) a[i] = 5; }

double array[512];
std::thread t1(foo, array, 256);
std::thread t2(foo, &array[256], 256);
```

Если оба потока не выходят за границы переданной им области и не происходит одновременной записи и чтения из памяти, то является ли такой код безопасным?
Как безопасно передавать указатель в поток?

Пожалуйста, посоветуйте профессиональную литературу по данной тематике.
Заранее благодарю всех за отклик.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но всё таки очень общий. Совет, попробуйте поделить вопрос на несколько отдельных более конкретных, узких вопросов. Не спрашивайте по поиску литературы, такие вопросы на данном ресурсе оффтоп.

Comment: Ответ на второй вопрос, да безопасно, да передавать указатель по значению. Что касается первого, как улучшить (подразумеваю время исполнения), то тут, конечно надо измерять, но что-то мне подсказывает, что однопоточная программа будет быстрее (при размере массива 1К все время сожрет lock)

Comment: @avp Спасибо за ответ. По поводу первой части вопроса. Улучшить с точки зрения структуры кода. Я хочу понять правильно ли используются возможности языка, с точки зрения опытных программистов. По поводу времени исполнения, многопоточная версия для длины последовательности больше 50 Мб показывает  сокращение времени выполнения на 40% (т.к. мы можем сгенерировать большее количество информации).

Comment: По поводу времени исполнения я бы попробовал заполнять в цикле мегабайтный буфер и писать его в файл обычным системным вызовом [write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write). Что же касается C++ кода, то возможно кто-то из любителей этого языка (к которым я не отношусь, считая его не заслуживающим тех усилий, которые он требует для полноценного использования (это я мягко сформулировал)) даст вам полезные советы.